# Maximum Likelihood to estimate function parameters from experimental data

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, point-estimation

**Problem**

I have a set of $n$ measurements $V_{i}^* = V^*(t_{i})$ of the observable $V$ in function of time $t$.

I also have the associated *sensibility errors* (determined by the measuring device's sensibility), which are also time dependent $\Delta V(t_{i})$. The statistical or random errors (the fluctuations of the real value) are negligible, together with the uncertainties on the measurement times $t_{i}$.

Assuming that the time dependence is

$$V(t) = V_{0}e^{-\frac{t}{c}}$$

we want to estimate the parameters $V_{0}$ and $c$ by using the Maximum Likelihood method.

**Considerations**:

- I know how to use MLE on statistical distributions which depend on parameters, but here $t$ is not a random variable so $V(t)$ can not be interpreted as a distribution
- On the contrary, every one of the n elements which constitute the sample $\{V_i\}_i$ is a random variable, and since I am given sensibility errors I can assume that every $V_i$ follows a *uniform distribution* with center on the measured value and half-width given by the error.

  Given this, the values of the parameters that maximize the probability of getting the measured values (which is the reasoning behind MLE) are those which make the function $V(t)$ pass between the error bars of my measurement.

  This presents the inconvenience that such values of the parameters are not unique because the probability of the occurrence of each value for a certain $V_i$ is constant in $(V_i^*\pm\Delta V_i)$, where $V_i^*$ is the measured value.

Which part of my reasoning is incorrect and how to determine the estimates of $V_{0}$ and $c$ analitically?

**Edit**

By *sensibility errors* I mean that the device does not react to changes in the real value smaller than the given error $\Delta V$. If it were e.g. $\Delta V = 1$, both $9.78$ and $10.34$ would be shown as $10$ on the device's screen and the results of the two measurements would both be $(10 \pm 0.5)$.

Comment: If the measurement errors are uniformly distributed then, as you said, the maximum likelihood parameters will not be unique in general. But, are the errors *really* uniform? Or is it just that you have uncertainty information given in the form of an interval?

Comment: I have uncertainty information given in the form of an interval, since the errors are sensibility errors of the measuring device. By sensibility errors I mean errors in reading the device's response, in this case it is a voltmeter with sensibility of (e.g.) 0.01V.

Comment: What does this interval mean precisely? For example, if it means $V_{true}$ falls within $V_{measured} \pm \Delta V$ with probability .99 (or even 1), this is different than the statement that $V_{true} - V_{measured}$ is uniformly distributed on $[-\Delta V, +\Delta V]$. Uniform measurement errors would be rather unusual. Do you know anything about the actual form of the distribution?

Comment: Sorry for not being precise, in my language this type of error is called "maximum error" or "sensibility error". Here's an example. Let's say that I have a chronometer with sensibility of 1 second, then two intervals of $9.78s$ and $10.34s$ will be measured as $10s$  by my device. Therefore both my measurements will be written as $(10 \pm 0.5)s$. This is the type of information I have, in the form $V_i \pm \Delta V_i$.
Replying to your last comment, the first is the case I'm talking about.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, you don't know the noise model (i.e. form of the error distribution), but the interval gives some kind of bounds on the extreme values the error may take. This is important for a couple reasons. 1) To perform maximum likelihood estimation, you need a likelihood function, which requires a noise model. 2) If the noise is not uniform (and it isn't for many instruments), then the maximum likelihood parameters may actually be unique.

Comment: I think the thing to do at this point would be to find a proper noise model that's consistent with the known error intervals and characteristics of the instrument. If possible, contact the manufacturer or conduct your own calibration tests. Otherwise postulate something plausible (maybe Gaussian?). Until then, I can't see a way to answer this question.

Comment: From the example you give, it appears that "sensibility errors" are due to the precision of the device, and are in effect roundoff errors.  Would this be correct?

Comment: @jbowman That is exactly correct: the device does not react to changes in the true value that are smaller than $\Delta V$.

Comment: @user20160 If the errors were _random errors_, their distribution (noise model) would be normal because of the Central Limit Theorem (with some assumptions). In this situation, $\Delta V$ is much bigger that the standard deviation of the (normal) distribution of random errors, so that the latter are negligible.